# How to install C# client library, particularly Google Cloud Text to Speech?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, client-library

I'm trying to use Google Cloud services such as Text-To-Speech in a Unity app.  On the quickstart page I've done the Before You Begin stuff. However, I can't "Install the Client Library". The provided line is:

Install-Package Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1 -Pre

However, when I put this into my terminal it says "'Install-Package' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I tried with Powershell too but got "Install-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Pre'.

At line:1 char:46

- Install-Package Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1 -Pre
- ~~~~
- CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Install-Package], ParameterBindingException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage"

I've tried searching online but it seems like I'm just missing a crucial step or something. Is there supposed to be anything I do before trying to install the client library? Am I doing it in the wrong place? Help appreciated, thanks!

Edit: 
Visual Studio displayed:

"Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1.1.0.0-beta02' does not exist in project 'Assembly-CSharp'
Package 'Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1.1.0.0-beta02' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\bwubr\Documents\EventHorizonVR\packages'
Executing nuget actions took 1.03 sec
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1 1.0.0-beta02'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', 
but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1 -Pre
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
 "

Comment: The Google Cloud Client Libraries aren't supported on Unity, I'm afraid. See https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/guides/platforms.html

Comment: Is Unity stuff Universal Windows Platform application? Is there any way around this?

Comment: I don't understand the question, I'm afraid - Unity *may* be able to generate UWP apps, but the binaries it creates for iOS, Android etc are very different. You *may* be able to get the REST-based packages (e.g. Google.Apis.Texttospeech.v1) to work with newer versions of Unity (not the .NET 3.5-based version) but it's still not a supported platform for those packages, and you may well encounter problems with authentication.

Answer (score 2):

`Install-Package` is a feature of the Nuget package manager console. You can open this from Visual Studio by following these steps:

1. Select the Tools menu
2. Select NuGet Package Manager
3. Package Manager Console

You can now run that command in the resultant window.

Alternatively, you can install it directly from the UI by selecting "Manage NuGet packages for the solution..." instead of "Package Manager Console".

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be moving me in the right direction. But now Visual Studio displays: "You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework" (full error message in edit). I'm not sure why the package wouldn't work.

Comment: That means that the package isn't compatible with .NET Framework 3.5 (which is quite old by now). You would have to change your project properties to target a newer version of the .NET Framework.